# Django: Can't set up custom django User model

Tags: python, django

I want to set up my own django User model because I need additional fields, but I am getting the error. I read a lot of posts but I didn't find solution. What is the problem?

Code models.py:

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True),
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=50, unique=True),
    city = models.TextField(max_length=30, blank=True),
    friends = models.ManyToManyField("Account", blank=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username']
```

Code admin.py

```
admin.site.register(User)
```

Code admin settings:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'users.apps.UsersConfig'
]

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.User'
```

Error:

```
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\rogal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\options.py", line 608, in get_field
    return self.fields_map[field_name]
KeyError: 'username'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\rogal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 973, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\rogal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 910, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\rogal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\rogal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 124, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "C:\Users\rogal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 438, in check
    all_issues = checks.run_checks(
  File "C:\Users\rogal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 77, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)
  File "C:\Users\rogal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\checks.py", line 55, in check_user_model
    if not cls._meta.get_field(cls.USERNAME_FIELD).unique and not any(
  File "C:\Users\rogal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\options.py", line 610, in get_field
    raise FieldDoesNotExist("%s has no field named '%s'" % (self.object_name, field_name))
django.core.exceptions.FieldDoesNotExist: User has no field named 'username'
```

Comment: try using `AbstractUser` instead of `AbstractBaseUser`

Comment: The same error.

Comment: On what command are you getting the above error?

Comment: Have you made migrations (`python manage.py makemigrations`) and applied them (`python manage.py migrate`) to make column actually appear in database in users table?

Comment: I can't make migrations because I am getting above error.

Comment: This error seems to occur in a running app, why do you think it will appear in makemigrations as well? It seems to be related to the page autoreloading feature, and should not reproduce while web server is down.

Comment: have you added `AUTH_USER_MODEL=` in settings.py file?

Comment: Arun T - added. @madbird I cant use python manage.py runserver or python manage.py makemigrations because I am getting the error

Comment: You can follow this link https://medium.com/@rajputgajanan50/custom-user-in-djnago-4923712e8f1

Comment: Is this application a fresh new one? which never had a User model migrated into database? or it had a user table before?

Comment: @Gajanan sent a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Why you are mentioning REQUIRED_Fields

```
USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
```

When you don't give arguments as Null = true or blank = true as default they become required ones. So Don't Mention them
Go like this:

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
     username = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True),
     email = models.EmailField(max_length=50, unique=True),
     city = models.TextField(max_length=30, blank=True),
     friends = models.ManyToManyField("Account", blank=True)
```

And define Your Admin.py

```
from .models import User
from django.contrib import admin


class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ["id", "username"]
    
admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```

Comment: The same error like above.